# Store Images in App_Data and address them absolute make errors

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, image

I've generated an image tag like below:

```
<td>
    <img src='@item.SourceAddress' alt="@item.Description"/>
</td>
```

and the result is somrthing like this:

```
<td>
    <img src='C:\Users\leo\Workspace\Team Foundation Server\Sources\HRS\HRS\App_Data\user\Photos\test.jpg' alt="desc"/>
</td>
```

The problem is I only see blank space and no image at all(in firefox I only see alt text). the path is correct. I copied the `img` tag itself into another html file and I see the image crystal clear.
somrthing that might help: I opened the source with firefox and when I clicked on source of image I got following error:

> Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol
>   (c) isn't associated with any program.

and sorry for terrible english by the way.
Edit: I Edited the title. It is make more sence now!

Comment: where does `SourceAddress` come from and how is it set?

Comment: It is stored in database. It shows the path to the image. I've stored the images in App_Data folder and their paths in database.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to you providing a local path name (i.e. a directory in C:) rather than a relative path via Razr.  If you start debug in Firefox then the console output sometimes eludes to this.

You could try something similar to:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Item.SourceAddress)" alt="desc"/>
```

And check that SourceAddress is in the format of:

```
~/MyImages/Photos/test.jpg
```

Also worth checking all the obvious things like double quotes over single quotes etc.

Comment: Edited because I really wasn't being helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what is the problem!

- First of all I used App_Data Folder to store files. this folder is special purpose and is used to store some special database files and IIS wont give direct access to this folder. and I had to make another folder like Image and store files there.
- Second problem is I gave the path directly from Root (C:\...). The Web Browser doesen't have access to the Server File System Directly (Due to some security reasons). Because of this I had to gave the path relative address. The absolut path should be used by Server Code only and not in html source.
  I managed to convert absolute path to relative like below:



  `public static class HttpServerUtilityExtensions
  {
      public static string RelativePath( this HttpServerUtilityBase utility, string path, HttpRequestBase context )
      {
          return path.Replace( context.ServerVariables[ "APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH" ], "/" ).Replace( @"\", "/" );
      }
  }`


  and:

      ``

Comment: I don't know why I can't Format It and why half of my writing is vanished!